# Why isn't this .png file showing?

Tags: html, css, email, png

Hi I'm working on an email for a company in HTML. They want me to display a png image with transparency but for some reason when I try it shows up like it can't find or load it. I've made sure to copy the specific source in sublime yet it still doesn't work. Is there a problem with .pngs in html? The .jpg is working fine.

[a picture showing my png failing to load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbv7p.jpg)

if it's relevant, I'm using the foundation framework.

```html
<body>
  
  <table class="body" data-made-with-foundation>
    <tr>
      <td class="float-center" align="center" valign="top">
        <center>
        <table class="container">
          <table class="row">
            <tr>
              <th class="small-12 large-12 first columns">
                <div class="imgbox">
                  <img class="mainimage" src= "assets/links/KDIemail1-bg.jpg" />

                  <div class="ricohtop">
                    RICOH CUSTOMERS
                  </div>
                  <img class= "toplogo" src="/assets/Links/kdi-toplogo.png" >
                  
                </div>
              </th>
              <th class="small-12 large-6 first columns">
              </th>
              <th class="expander"></th>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </table>
          
        </center>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

Edit: I'm an idiot. It was being blocked by the red div and there was a sass error I didn't notice. Thanks to everyone who answered I kinda wasted your time though haha!

Comment: @MichaelCoker wait I'm confused isn't it public? It's in the assets folder. The same place the jpg file is.

Comment: no worries... glad you solved your problem!

Answer (score 2):

```
<img class="mainimage" src= "assets/links/KDIemail1-bg.jpg" />

<img class= "toplogo" src="/assets/Links/kdi-toplogo.png" >
```

Your second image is missing a / and the src has a extra / at the start. Also Links is capitalized.

Please try this fix

```
<img class= "toplogo" src="assets/links/kdi-toplogo.png" />
```

Comment: Missing a `/` really? Where would that be?

Comment: Ok, got it! A well-formed HTML is always welcomed ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the leading slash `/` from the PNG image path.

On Unix-based systems (e.g. macOS, Linux, etc) a leading `/` indicates a path from the file system *root*. In your HTML, I believe you need instead a *relative path* (i.e., one without the leading `/`).

As correctly noted by NewbLeech, might be a good idea to close your `<img>` tag as well.